# Any javascript canvas library powerful enough to replace dom?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing

does anyone know of a javascript canvas library that is not just for "game apps" but also makes it easy to do things we can do using just "Dom".

I've looked at a couple of "canvas/art libraries" but they often lack the ability to do simple "dom" things like creating a new TextBox/CheckBox (a cool-looking checkbox that is browser-independent).

Also, my second question is that is there anyway to track the "mouse scroll event"? I think it would be ncessary to be able to track the "mouse scroll event" if we were to roll out our own version of "dom" using javascript painting.

(Btw please don't quote stuff like whatever's painted is not accessible to the blind at all because screen readers can't make sense of it etc, because my web app is not for the blind)

Comment: @Pacerier: Whatever you are doing, I can almost guarantee you that some blind person somewhere will be interested at some point, no matter how out there the idea sounds. For instance, there are a lot of blind video-gamers, and what's more there are quite a few **unbelievably good** blind video gamers. Ignorance is one thing, but blatantly saying "I don't care about group x because they aren't important to me" is kind of... well, 'crappy' is the only diplomatic way I can say it. Just my 2c.

Comment: @Matthew Scharley I'm stating that i'm not interested in answers like "whatever's painted is not accessible to the blind" since it does not help/answer this question in anyway. My comment there is to make it explicit

Comment: @Matthew Scharley tell that to people who build canvas games don't tell that to me

Comment: Have you looked at [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/test/demo)?